# Как типизировать конфиг вебпака экпортный модуль?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Пытаюсь типизировать вот этот файл webpack конфига. Получаю ошибку. "any" относится только к типу, но используется здесь как значение. Как можно это исправить?

```
    module.exports:any = {
      devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true, 
      },
    };
```

Comment: Сгенерируйте d.ts

Comment: у меня есть типы при наведение просто не понимаю, как их прописать по синтаксису явным образом

Comment: удалите `:any` в строке `module.exports:any`. Так как вы используете `module.exports` для экспорта объекта, не нужно указывать тип данных

Comment: спасибо, тогда указываю только где я получаю данный файл const developmentConfig: devServer = require('./dev.config');